# React Hooks, updated value of setState shows initial values in another component

Tags: reactjs

Just starting to explore React Hooks. I want to create an API fetch component, import it into another component - so that I can reuse the API fetch component in other components.

What's happening is that I set my initial state values:

Api.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useUserFetch = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState({
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    data: [],
  });
```

then do an async fetch inside useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserQuery() {
      await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
          console.log('API RESPONSE: ', response)
          if (response.status === 200 && response.status < 400) {
            response.json().then((respData) => {
              setUsers({ loading: false, error: false, data: respData })
            })
          } else {
            response.json().then(err => {
              setUsers({ loading: false, error: err, data: [] })
            })
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          setUsers({ loading: false, error: err, data: [] })
        })
    }
    fetchUserQuery()
  }, [])
```

if the response status is 200(ish), then change my state array to include the update values of the response.  Same for error handling.  Once the fetch has completed, I check and return the values of loading, error and data (as well as console logging the values):

```
if (users.loading) {
    console.log('API LOADING: ', users.loading)
    return "Loading..."
  }

  if (users.error) {
    console.log('API ERROR: ', users.error)
    return "Error..."
  }

  if (users.data) {
    console.log('API DATA: ', users.data)
    return users;
  }
```

As you can see, the last check is for data, and if there's data, console log the API DATA and return the data.  The problem is, the console output of data right before data is returned, shows the users array (it works, see include console log below).  However, when I import Api.js into my Contacts.js and attempt to output the data, it still shows the initial values of the users state.

Contacts.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useUserFetch } from '../Api';

const Users = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(useUserFetch());
    console.log('CONTACT STATE: ', userData)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUserState() {
            const userJsonData = await userData
            setUserData(userJsonData)
        }
        fetchUserState()
    }, [])

    if (userData.loading) return "Loading...";
    if (userData.error) return userData.error.message
    if (userData.data) return JSON.stringify(userData.data)

    return true
};

export default Users
```

Here's what the console shows (in exact order):

> API LOADING:  true
>
> Contacts.js:7 CONTACT STATE:  Loading...
>
> Api.js:14 API RESPONSE:  Response {type: "cors", url:
>   "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", redirected: false,
>   status: 200, ok: true, …}
>
> Api.js:42 API DATA:  (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
>   {…}, {…}]
>
> Contacts.js:7 CONTACT STATE:  Loading...

So my first question; is this an issue with setState being asynchronous?  If so, how can I handle this to ensure that when I return my user state, my Contacts.js gets the updated values.  Or is it an async in my useEffect in either file?  Or something else?  I'm just trying to wrap my head around the new Hooks and would explore Redux/MobX or Context API in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html),

> **How does a custom Hook get isolated state?** Each call to a Hook gets isolated state. Because we call [custome hook](modified word, in docs it is a hook name from example) directly, from React’s point of view our component just calls useState and useEffect.

As we already know, we can call useState and useEffect many times in one component, and they will be completely independent.

As the state are isolated, you must have a separate reference to your custom hook, pass it to `useEffect` as second argument, so that you will get a state properly,

```
const App = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(useUserFetch());
    let users = useUserFetch(); //Get seperate reference

    console.log('CONTACT STATE: ', userData)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUserState() {
            const userJsonData = await users //get data
            setUserData(userJsonData)
        }
        fetchUserState()
    },[users]) //Pass as dependency

    if (userData.loading) return "Loading...";
    if (userData.error) return userData.error.message
    if (userData.data) return JSON.stringify(userData.data)

    return true
};
```

Comment: Yes, that was the missing piece.   Thanks for the ref to the docs and answer!